# What does integer-class type mean in C++ since integer is a built in type

Tags: c++, types, c++20

While reading through the documentation of `std::numeric_limits` I came across the following [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

> Specializations for all **integer-class types** are also provided. (since C++20)

My question is that what do we mean by *integer class types* in the above statement. I mean, I know that `int` is a built in type in C++. And we can provide user-defined class in C++. But I never read about an integer-class type. I tried searching that phrase on google, but didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: I was going to point out the existence of `short`, `long`, `unsigned` etc., but the link you've shown already mentions all of those and then has the "since C++20" line, which implies that they mean something else by "integer-class". So I'm not sure what types are meant here.

Comment: See [numeric_limits::is_integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer)

Comment: I suspect that this refers to, mostly, `char8_t`.

Comment: That must mean none-standard platform extensions (library types or core types) such as 128b integers. If you read a few lines below the mentioned point, things get clearer also look at [`std::is_integral`] [1].  [1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral

Comment: @NathanPierson I would read that as the _specializations_ are provided since C++20, not the types themselves.

Answer (score 22):

From [the history](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/types/numeric_limits&diff=120460&oldid=112829) we can see that this pertains to the iterator **concepts** added in C++20; in particular, [iterator.concept.winc]/2 says

> A type `I` is an *integer-class type* if it is in a set of implementation-defined types that behave as integer types do, as defined below.
>
> [*Note 1*: An integer-class type is not necessarily a class type.  — *end note*]

The library is given permission to use one of these suitably integer-like types to represent the sizes of ranges and the distances between elements of ranges.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.winc#11
in the C++20 standard mentions that `numeric_limits<I>` must be defined for such an integer-class type `I`.

Comment: In other words, _integer-class type_ is standardese for _integer-like types_...

Answer (score 11):

It's yet another set of integer types, that are neither standard integer types nor extended integer types.

> There are five standard signed integer types: “signed char”, “short
> int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type
> provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
> There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer
> types. The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively
> called signed integer types.

A problem here is that the typedef `intmax_t` must be defined as the largest of these integer types (thus its name :-).

Now if an implementation were to define a new set of "integer-class types" that are not "standard" or "extended" integers, but merely "integer-like", it could use those types without changing `intmax_t`.

Saves us from an ABI break for all previous uses of `intmax_t` parameters.

Comment: This sounds like it's just formalising what gcc/clang already did..........

Comment: Yes. They have "as an extension" non-standard integer types that are not "extended integer types" either. By calling them "integer-like" instead, they would become standard types (but not "standard integer types").  :-)